# how to add background color to pdf file in iphone app

Tags: iphone, xcode, pdf, background, uiimage

i am generating pdf file using this way now it works fine but background is white i want to give some color to background so is it possible to give backgorund color.

```
  - (void) generatePdfWithFilePath: (NSString *)thefilePath

  {
  UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(thefilePath, CGRectZero, nil);


 NSInteger currentPage = 0;
 BOOL done = NO;
 do 
  {

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, pageSize.width, pageSize.height), nil);


    currentPage++;
    [self drawPageNumber:currentPage];

    //Draw a border for each page.
    [self drawBorder];

    //Draw text fo our header.
    [self drawHeader];

    //Draw a line below the header.
    [self drawLine];

    //Draw some text for the page.
    [self drawText];

    //Draw an image
    [self drawImage];
    done = YES;


     } 
  while (!done);


 UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use this code inside do while loop

```
CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(currentContext, [UIColor redColor].CGColor );
CGContextFillRect(currentContext, pdfpageFrame);
```

This will solve your Problem

Comment: I get an "Thread1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x40)" - Error